# Can't see Journey Builder in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I need to use Journey Builder but I don't see it in the dropdown. Only Automation Studio and Behavioral Triggers are showing.

Is this because my organization doens't have the correct tier of SFMC or is there a setting somewhere I need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Journey builder is not available in Basic, can be purchased as an add-on in Pro, and comes standard in Corporate and Enterprise editions of SFMC.

If you know JB should be included in your edition, there might be a potential permission issue, of your user simply not being provided with access to Journey Builder, despite it being part of your edition. In that case, I would reach out to your admin and ask for your user permissions to be updated.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Indeed, we have the Pro edition so I'm guessing we never bought the JB add-on for our instance.